# How can i know about which of your watchers is taking the most time and how to prevent about that?

Tags: angularjs

How can i know about which watcher is in more use and how to prevent such ?
And one more thing is how to know about which page is taking more time ?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en

Comment: Yeah, It helps me and i have collect the data also but how can i know about which  ranges of watchers and time period  is good for that site?